# Not able to deploy python script to heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I can't able deploy my script to Heroku because of below error

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing "python-3.6.0"
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing requirements with pip
   /app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/bin/steps/pip-install: line 7: /app/.heroku/python/bin/pip: No such file or directory
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed
```

I have setup virtualenv in that folder which is shown below

```
env  Procfile  namaztimesms.py  requirements.txt  runtime.txt
```

Now my **Procfile** contain

```
web: python namaztimesms.py
```

**requirements.txt** file contains

```
beautifulsoup4==4.5.3
requests==2.13.0
```

**runtime.txt** contains

```
"python-3.6.0"
```

I don't know what I do next??Is something wrong with virtualenv or it has not installed properly??

Comment: If you are trying to do scraping then I suggest you to try Scrapy and then deploy it on scrapinghub ... It is far better than deploying it on Heroku. In scrapinghub you can track your scraped items easily.

Comment: I want it to use as scheduler in Heroku but in scrappinghub there is no scheduler